# IOS: How to Download Google Docs files using ios google drive sdk API?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-api-objc-client

I integrated google drivs sdk with my ios app. At present am using the following code to download the files from my google drive a/c based on download url link. But when i try to download the google docs files (which has mime type **application/vnd.google-apps.document**) there is no download url link from google drive library. In that case how can i download the google docs data?. Can i use **alternateLink** instead of download url link?. Any help must be appreciated.

**My Code:**

```
- (void)loadFileContent {

GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher =
[self.driveService.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:[[self.driveFiles objectAtIndex:selectedFileIdx] downloadUrl]];

[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"\nfile %@ downloaded successfully from google drive", [[self.driveFiles objectAtIndex:selectedFileIdx] originalFilename]);

        //saving the downloaded data into temporary location

    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);            

    }
}];
```

}

Comment: Did you manage to download the files ? I would like to know how did worked it out through. I am also trying to download the files, but so far I am unable to find any resource that would help me with it.

Comment: @Shailesh,
yes, i can able to download the files from google drive. In my case i initiated the download operation when user tap on file name. What issue you are facing ?

Comment: I am using the code Google has provided the one of their samples. Name of the project is "DriveSample"
I am getting the export/download URL NULL. 
It fails to download totally.

Comment: Here is the URL that I am using for reference -- https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/DriveSample/DriveSampleWindowController.m?#691

Comment: @Shailesh, I just posted my code below you can check it. Usually while fetch the file list info google also give you the download url link that is different for native google docs and your attached files. When you know the download url link then you can initiate the download operation using that url.

Answer (score 5):

Here the steps to download the file from google drive. It will work for both file and also google docs.

Step 1:

Fetch the file list and store it into an array or dict with related file download link url:

```
- (void)loadDriveFiles {
fileFetchStatusFailure = NO;

//for more info about fetching the files check this link
//https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list    
GTLQueryDrive *query2 = [GTLQueryDrive queryForChildrenListWithFolderId:[parentIdList lastObject]];
query2.maxResults = 1000;

// queryTicket can be used to track the status of the request.
[self.driveService executeQuery:query2
              completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                  GTLDriveChildList *children, NSError *error) {
                  GTLBatchQuery *batchQuery = [GTLBatchQuery batchQuery];                      
                  //incase there is no files under this folder then we can avoid the fetching process
                  if (!children.items.count) {                          
                      [self.driveFiles removeAllObjects];
                      [fileNames removeAllObjects];                          
                      [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTableDataFromMainThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];                          
                      return ;
                  }

                  if (error == nil) {
                      int totalChildren = children.items.count;
                      count = 0;

                      [self.driveFiles removeAllObjects];
                      [fileNames removeAllObjects];                                                    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603432/listing-all-files-from-specified-folders-in-google-drive-through-ios-google-driv/14610713#14610713
                      for (GTLDriveChildReference *child in children) {
                          GTLQuery *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesGetWithFileId:child.identifier];                              
                          query.completionBlock = ^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLDriveFile *file, NSError *error) {

                              //increment count inside this call is very important. Becasue the execute query call is asynchronous
                              count ++;
                              NSLog(@"Google Drive: retrieving children info: %d", count);                                  
                              if (error == nil) {
                                  if (file != nil) { //checking the file resource is available or not
                                      //only add the file info if that file was not in trash
                                      if (file.labels.trashed.intValue != 1 )
                                          [self addFileMetaDataInfo:file numberOfChilderns:totalChildren];
                                  }

                                  //the process passed all the files then we need to sort the retrieved files
                                  if (count == totalChildren) {
                                      NSLog(@"Google Drive: processed all children, now stopping HUDView - 1");
                                      [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTableDataFromMainThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
                                  }
                              } else {
                                  //the file resource was not found
                                  NSLog(@"Google Drive: error occurred while retrieving file info: %@", error);

                                  if (count == totalChildren) {
                                      NSLog(@"Google Drive: processed all children, now stopping HUDView - 2");
                                      [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTableDataFromMainThread)
                                                             withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
                                  }                                      
                              }                                  
                          };                              
                          //add the query into batch query. Since we no need to iterate the google server for each child.
                          [batchQuery addQuery:query];
                      }                          
                      //finally execute the batch query. Since the file retrieve process is much faster because it will get all file metadata info at once
                      [self.driveService executeQuery:batchQuery
                                    completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                        GTLDriveFile *file,
                                                        NSError *error) {
                                    }];

                      NSLog(@"\nGoogle Drive: file count in the folder: %d", children.items.count);
                  } else {
                      NSLog(@"Google Drive: error occurred while retrieving children list from parent folder: %@", error);
                  }
              }];
```

}

step-2:
add the file metadata info

```
    -(void)addFileMetaDataInfo:(GTLDriveFile*)file numberOfChilderns:(int)totalChildren
{
    NSString *fileName = @"";
    NSString *downloadURL = @"";

    BOOL isFolder = NO;

    if (file.originalFilename.length)
        fileName = file.originalFilename;
    else
        fileName = file.title;

    if ([file.mimeType isEqualToString:@"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"]) {
        isFolder = YES;
    } else {
        //the file download url not exists for native google docs. Sicne we can set the import file mime type
        //here we set the mime as pdf. Since we can download the file content in the form of pdf
        if (!file.downloadUrl) {
            GTLDriveFileExportLinks *fileExportLinks;

            NSString    *exportFormat = @"application/pdf";

            fileExportLinks = [file exportLinks];
            downloadURL = [fileExportLinks JSONValueForKey:exportFormat];
        } else {
            downloadURL = file.downloadUrl;
        }
    }

    if (![fileNames containsObject:fileName]) {
        [fileNames addObject:fileName];

        NSArray *fileInfoArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:file.identifier, file.mimeType, downloadURL,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:isFolder], nil];
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fileInfoArray forKey:fileName];

        [self.driveFiles addObject:dict];
    }
}
```

step-3:
download the file based on file select on the table row

```
    NSString *downloadUrl = [[[[self.driveFiles objectAtIndex:selectedFileIdx] allValues] objectAtIndex:0]
                   objectAtIndex:download_url_link];
NSLog(@"\n\ngoogle drive file download url link = %@", downloadUrl);    
GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher =
[self.driveService.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:downloadUrl];    
//async call to download the file data
[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"\nfile %@ downloaded successfully from google drive", self.selectedFileName);

        //saving the downloaded data into temporary location
        [data writeToFile:<path> atomically:YES];               
    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thank you ! It worked. :) 
Though I feel, Google needs to work on their API documentation. Its way to complicated to implement in our projects. Dropbox,SkyDrive on the other hand have simple and pretty straight forward procedure.

Comment: @Shailesh, Awesome!!! :-) yeah you are right :-)  when i started integrate the google drive i faced a lot.

Comment: @loganathan will this block crashes app if the data will be more then 1 GB?

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander that i am not sure about it. I did not check this user case path.

Comment: please help mi how download in uibutton click

Comment: parentIdList how to get this parent list

Comment: @loganathan As of march 2016, I found out that there is no more    downloadUrl    property for GTLDriveFile object, but there is an alternative for this: 
    "// A link for downloading the content of the file in a browser. This is only
// available for files with binary content in Drive.
 property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *webContentLink; "

Answer (score 3):

Documents in Google Docs native formats can't be downloaded as other files, but only exported to different supported formats using the `exportLinks` URLs.

For more details and the list of supported formats check the Google Drive SDK documentation:

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents

Comment: I checked the documentation. But there i can't find any example related to Objectice-C. So can you please tell me how can i get the export type  application/pdf from the GTLDriveFileExportLinks class.

Comment: The Objective-C sample at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/DriveSample/DriveSampleWindowController.m?#691 shows how to download or export files

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem before. Specifically, I did not find downloadurl for the native documents created in Google Document. They are null. Only those created through DrEdit (solutions exemplified in Drive SDK) are associated with downloadUrl.

The solution is actually embedded in the attribute: *JSON* in **GTLDriveFileExportLinks** instance, which returns NSMutableDictionary*. You can choose to view the content of JSON object via access *JSONString* attribute. The JSON mutatable dictionary can be obtained through querying *exportLinks* in **GTLDriveFile** instance. The example is as below:

```
GTLDriveFile *file = files.items[0]; // assume file is assigned to a valid instance.
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = file.exportLinks.JSON; 
NSLog(@"URL:%@.", [jsonDict objectForKey:@"text/plain"]);
```