# listing all files from specified folders in Google Drive through IOS Google Drive SDK

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-api-objc-client

Actually i integrated google drive sdk with my ios app. I can able to retrieve/upload the files in google drive through google drive ios sdk. But the retrieving files list from specified parent folder taking so much time.

**Here the steps and the code which was i am using.**

First am getting the children's of the specified parent folder then am getting the **GTLDriveChildReference** of each child then 
then am querying with the child reference identifier.

This is huge process for me. Also it request google server each time. Any better way there to just pass the parent folder id in a query and pulling the files from that parent folder.

```
   -(void)getFileListFromSpecifiedParentFolder {
        GTLQueryDrive *query2 = [GTLQueryDrive queryForChildrenListWithFolderId:<some_id or root>];
        query2.maxResults = 1000;

        // queryTicket can be used to track the status of the request.
        [self.driveService executeQuery:query2
            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                            GTLDriveChildList *children, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"\nGoogle Drive: file count in the folder: %d", children.items.count);
                //incase there is no files under this folder then we can avoid the fetching process
                if (!children.items.count) {
                    return ;
                }

                if (error == nil) {
                    for (GTLDriveChildReference *child in children) {

                        GTLQuery *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesGetWithFileId:child.identifier];

                        // queryTicket can be used to track the status of the request.
                        [self.driveService executeQuery:query
                            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                GTLDriveFile *file,
                                                NSError *error) {

                                                NSLog(@"\nfile name = %@", file.originalFilename);
                                                }];
                    }
                }
            }];
    }
```

Any help that might be appreciated.

Comment: there is not any method called "queryForChildrenListWithFolderId" in drive iOS sdk now, can you tell me what should i use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try combining queries in a [batch query](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction#Batch_Operations), like

```
GTLBatchQuery *batchQuery = [GTLBatchQuery batchQuery];
for (GTLDriveChildReference *child in children) {
  GTLQuery *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesGetWithFileId:child.identifier];
  query.completionBlock = ^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLDriveFile *file, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error=%@, file name = %@", error, file.title);
  };
  [batchQuery addQuery:query];
}
[driveService executeQuery:batchQuery completionHandler:...]
```

If automatic fetching of [result pages](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction#Result_Pages) is enabled (`service.shouldFetchNextPages = YES`) then try to set the maxResults property of queries to avoid the need for the library to make multiple fetches. For example, if there are 100 or fewer results for a query, a maxResults value of 100 will retrieve them with a single fetch.

Requests for [partial responses](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction#Partial_Responses) are also a bit faster and use much less memory, particularly for large results.

Look at [http logs](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction#Logging_HTTP_Server_Traffic) for a better idea of the response sizes for your queries.

Comment: This is what i want. It seems works much faster after applied batch query.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using the following code (which only requires one query rather than multiple queries):

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' IN parents", <the folderID>];

[self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                          GTLDriveFileList *files,
                                                          NSError *error) {
...
}];
```

Seems to be working well thus far.

Comment: Are you getting subfolders using this query? I think that you can only retrieve files....

Comment: Please suggest me., 

I'm getting the error by using this code .

n error occurred: Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Login Required)" UserInfo=0x8f72a40 {error=Login Required, GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x8f647a0: {message:"Login Required" code:401 data:[1]}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Login Required)}

Comment: how to get folder id? @Bern11