# How to retrieve file content from google drive API for iOS ,if the user is restricted from downloading that file

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I am using the following code for downloading the google drive file (only pdf file) in my iOS app and displaying contents in a UIWebView.

```
      GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher =
  [self.driveService.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:self.driveFile.downloadUrl];


  [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    if (error == nil) {

        [self.webvieww loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];

    } else {
      NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
      [DrEditUtilities showErrorMessageWithTitle:@"Unable to load file"
                                         message:[error description]
                                        delegate:self];
    }
  }];
```

But if GTLDriveFile's restricted property is true (which means when the user is prevented from downloading this file) then downloadUrl will be nil.
How I can display the contents of the file in such case.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/20392458/2522603

Comment: this is my query                                                                       GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];                                                          
                                        query.q = @"sharedWithMe";                                      
my query works perfect, if the owner of a file set "Prevent viewers from downloading" while sharing a file.Then downloadUrl will be nil.

Comment: Maybe the only way would be to use a webview to preview the file inside drive. User would need to login (once) to the webview. (Sorry its called webview in android but i guess ios has an equivalent)

Comment: @Zig Mandel  you are right, I can use NSURL from 'alternateLink' property of GTLDriveFile to load the file inside google drive in a UIWebView .And user needs to login again to the web view.Any other possibilities are there to load the document ..