# Cannot access any mime-type file from ios-quickeditor sample code

Tags: ios, oauth, google-drive-api

Had code that worked with OAuth 1.0, have to change it for OAuth 2.0. Needed some practice for OAuth 2.0 and found iOS-quickeditor on GitHub. Followed directions, made a client ID and secret, and updated the code. Now I wanted to get a list of all my files on my Google Drive.

I tried changing the query.q 'mimeType' in method QEFilesListViewController.m / loadDriveFiles to try an access different kinds of files and received no files in the filter response. For example, I want to list google spreadsheets with mime type.

```
- (void)loadDriveFiles {
    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
    query.q = @"mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'";
```

Is it only possible to access files created using the indicated clientId / clientSecret instead of being able to access files of any type created by any other app? If so, then how?

Answer (score 0):

Dur. Forgot to alter the scope of the query beyond the app using "kGTLAuthScopeDrive". Referenced this answer:

[Listing All files and folders from Google Drive in DrEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391734/listing-all-files-and-folders-from-google-drive-in-dredit)