# How to download PDF file url from google drive with latest IOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

To work with google Drive, google developer portals says that

https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files#reading_files

## 1

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@?alt=media",file.identifier];
```

This is my url for normal document/text file and

## 2

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@/export?alt=media&mimeType=application/pdf", file.identifier];
```

This is my url for pdf files.. however none of url works for me

I come to now for #1 that if I replace my url with kClientID as

```
NSString *url = [NSStringstringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@?key=%@", file.identifier,kClientID];
```

Its working  fine for normal text/document files…. But not sure how to access PDF file url.

Comment: can't understand your question...!! what you want exactly?????

Comment: @Lion, I'm not able to download pdf file from google drive

Comment: where is the code that you have tried to download file? you have just add three strings which contains urls!!

Comment: the second one as per google documentation but it's not working with me :( not sure what mistake I made

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google drive sdk api you can download files something like,

```
 GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher =
[self.driveService.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:downloadUrl];    
//async call to download the file data
 [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
if (error == nil) {
    NSLog(@"\nfile %@ downloaded successfully from google drive", self.selectedFileName);

    //saving the downloaded data into temporary location
    [data writeToFile:<path> atomically:YES];               
} else {
    NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
}
}];
```

You will get files as data. You can store it in `document directory`. Or you can load it on `webview` to show. If file is `pdf` then you can load it on `webview`.

You can refer [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450999/ios-how-to-download-google-docs-files-using-ios-google-drive-sdk-api)  for more details. refer it's answer all step mentioned.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I need to work with GTMSessionFetcher, not with the API version 2 i.e with GTMHTTPFetcher ;(